# How to stop content scrolling over mat-tabs, when tabs are fixed

Tags: css, angular, scroll, angular-material, tabs

I need mat-tabs to stick to the top, I went through this [Stackoverflow anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48517730/how-to-fix-the-header-of-mat-tab), and fixed the tabs on top by adding this to the css:

```
:host ::ng-deep .mat-tab-header {
   position: fixed;
}
```

This works for fixing the tabs but, now the content flows over the tabs. Is there a way to fix this?

[Stackblitz link for the problem](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-w8yg4z?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftab-group-animations-example.css). Please let me know if there is another way to stick the tabs on top or make the content not scroll on to the tabs.

Thank you.

Comment: A mat-tab is a tab that is inside the same page as the main tab, that is like a popup. Right? I don't want to post the wrong answer

Comment: mat-tab are the tabs in the main web web page. I want the mat-tab heder to stick to the top. The content should scroll properly. check the stackblitz link and scroll the content on tab 1. For reference, check https://material.angular.io/components/tabs/overview

Answer (score 1):

You can just add background color + z-index: 1111 if I understood your question correctly.

```
:host ::ng-deep .mat-tab-header {
   position: fixed;
   background: white;
   z-index: 1111;
}
```